# Render a new Component without using router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created an application to React, and when it starts, the App component is rendered. I would like that when the user clicks on a button or link, the button or link has to be in the App component when clicking on that link, another component will be rendered but not inside the App component but only the new component will be rendered in the same URL. As for this new component, it has to have a similar button so that when the user clicks, only the App component is rendered and this component that the user has clicked on is not rendered, only the App component.

I do not know if I explained myself correctly. Ask me any question if you need some clarification.

My App component is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Touch from './Touch';
import '../App.css';

class App extends Component{

    render() { 
        return(
          <div>
                <div className="wrapper" >
                    <button >NewComponent</button><NewComponent />???
                    <h1>Google Cloud Speech with Socket.io</h1>

                    <p id="ResultText"><span className="greyText">No Speech to Text yet</span></p>

                </div>

                <div className="buttonWrapper" >

                        <button className="btn" id="startRecButton" type="button"> Start recording</button>
                        <button className="btn" id="stopRecButton" type="button"> Stop recording</button>

                </div>


          </div>
         ); 
}
}


export default App
```

My index.js is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import App from './components/App.js';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: I think the URL is changing in those cases; there's a way to do it without changing URL just using "/", without using routers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to use `react-router` you will need to store a value in the component's state and change the rendering method to reflect which button was pressed. If you want each of those component to include the button you need to switch, do the following :

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {renderA: false,};
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({renderA: !prevState.renderA}));
    };

    render = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.renderA ? 
                    <ComponentA handleClick={this.handleCLick}/>:
                    <ComponentB handleClick={this.handleCLick}/>
                }
            </div>
        );
    };
} export default App;

// ComponentA
class ComponentA extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                // what you want inside your first page here
                <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            </div>
        );
    }
} export default ComponentA;

// ComponentB
class ComponentB extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                // what you want inside your second page here
                <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}
            </div>
        );
    }
} export default ComponentB;
```

But using `react-router` might also suits your case, and if you are going to write a large app, you should use it instead of rendering differents children components within the same one, based on users inputs.

Comment: I have edited my question, I think I did not explain correctly before.

Comment: You do think I should create a third component which includes both other components in order to know in which of them the state changed?

Comment: You will always need a top component that contains your app. So you will need to wrap what's currently in your <App/> into a  <componentA/>, wrap your other page into a <componentB/> and render componentA or componentB based on the App's state. You can have a button in both components A and B that's change App's state and make it render the other component

Comment: So in the top component that wrap the component A and B is where is I need to use:


    render = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.renderA ? <componentA/>: <componentB/>}
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

Comment: And create in both components a contructor like the one you post before:

constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {renderA: false,};
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState((prevProps) => {renderA: !prevProps.renderA})
    }

Comment: I am getting the following warnings when compiling the app:

  Line 13:  Unexpected labeled statement                                           no-labels
  Line 13:  'renderA:' is defined but never used                                 no-unused-labels
  Line 13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: What is your Line 13 ? Do you use the variable you set in state to choose which component to render ?

Comment: This is the line 13:

     this.setState((prevProps) => {renderA: !prevProps.renderA})

Comment: Ok my bad, it should be this.setState((prevState) => ({renderA: !prevState.renderA}));

Answer (score 0):

If the URL stay the same, I don't think React-Router might help you.

If you want that `App` Component is not loaded, I think you should create two more Component, a `Wrapper` one, and the new component you want to display (from now on `newComponent`). What I suggest is:

- Creating a property `isButtonClicked` inside the state of the `Wrapper` Component;
- Creating a function `handleButtonClick()` inside the `Wrapper` Component:

  ```
  handleButtonClick() => {
     let isButtonClicked = !this.state.isButtonClicked;
     this.setState({ isButtonClicked });
  }
  ```
- In the `render()` method of the `Wrapper` component, you write something like this:

  ```
  render() {
      if (this.state.isButtonClicked)
          return <App />
      else
          return <NewComponent />
  }
  ```

Then, in both `App` and `NewComponent`, if you click on the button, you call the `this.props.handleButtonClick()`, which will lead to a change of the state of `Wrapper` Component, therefore to a change of what is shown on the screen.